# Blender 2.8 - Particle Instance not rendered

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, instances

I am playing around with the newest Blender 2.8 Build for Windows 64bit

blender-2.80.0-git.a205493426b-windows64

I tried to create a firework scene, where particles emit particles by using a particle instance modifier. The basic animation is a simple explode modifier.

The animation shows fine in the 3D viewport, either with Cycles or Eevee choosen.
But as soon as I try to finally render the scene, the particle system, attached to the particle instances is not rendered at all. To be precise - it seems that the particles stuck to the particle instances and flowing around. 
But as I said - the 3D viewport is OK.

The constant issues with the Particle Instance Modifier, that the scale has to be applied to the meshes, has been taken into account.

Anybody else here with similar Blender 2.8 issues? Or has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Given that 2.8 is still in development, this is quite possibly a bug...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of old at this point but I just figured out this issue so I'm going to post how to make all the particle instances show up in case someone in the future needs help figuring it out.

In the Particle Instance modifier properties there is a check box for "Create Along Paths". Just make sure that is checked and they will show up. Easy fix that might not have been there in the betas for 2.8 but some of the tutorials I've watched so far seem to have left out this important part.